# How to deploy angular 4 app to azure web app by local git

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I try too much to deploy. I can deploy nodeJS to azure web app but I can't deploy Angular4. It show "service unavailable" always. How to deploy it by local git. (Development team using git for control version)

Comment: https://sajeetharan.com/2020/02/14/deploy-angular9-app-to-azure-with-github-actions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create web app for angular js and go to application settings

> WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=10.6.0

[image]

2) Click on Deployment options and configure your source code repository , i am using bit bucket here for demo

[image]

[image]

3) Now build your source code locally using following command and make sure app is working properly

- npm install
- ng build -prod
- ng serve

ng build -prod created dist folder for deployment.

[image]

4) Create web.config file and add into root level in your source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
          <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
            <remove statusCode="404"/>
            <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/index.html"/>
        </httpErrors>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
          <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

5) create "package.json" on root level

```
{
  "name": "scoring",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build –prod ",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "prod": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.41",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

6) Make sure "package-lock.json" file created and on your root folder level

package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates.

7) Created ".deployment"  on root level

```
[config]
command = deploy.cmd
```

8) Now you need KUDU Deployment Script

```
@if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

:: ----------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script
:: Version: 1.0.8
:: ----------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
)
goto Deployment

:: Utility Functions
:: -----------------

:SelectNodeVersion

IF DEFINED KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD (
  :: The following are done only on Windows Azure Websites environment
  call %KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp" (
    SET /p NODE_EXE=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp" (
    SET /p NPM_JS_PATH=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED NODE_EXE (
    SET NODE_EXE=node
  )

  SET NPM_CMD="!NODE_EXE!" "!NPM_JS_PATH!"
) ELSE (
  SET NPM_CMD=npm
  SET NODE_EXE=node
)

goto :EOF

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

:Deployment
echo Handling node.js deployment.

:: 1. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)

:: 2. Select node version
call :SelectNodeVersion

:: 3. Install npm packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --only=prod
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
goto end

:: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.
```

9) Go to console and verify

[image]

[image]

[image]

10) Go and verify build success or error logs

[image]

11) Hit Azure web app url and see your app up and running , it's continues deployment so once you checking code into repository build automatically pushed to azure.

Answer (score 2):

Have you *build* your application first? For example if you use angular-cli using:

```
ng build --prod
```

This will create a **dist** directory containing the build artifacts. In order to use client side routing and to get ride of some console errors you should put a web.config within the dist folder:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
     </staticContent>

      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now all you have to do is to **push** the content of the dist directory to the your web app. To do this, initialize a git repository within the dist directory using

```
git init
```

Add everything to your local repository using:

```
git add -A
```

And commit it:

```
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Then add your azure web app git repository:

```
git remote add azure https://<username>@localgitdeployment.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/localgitdeployment.git
```

And push the content to it:

```
git push azure master
```

See also [Local Git Deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git)

Comment: I followed all the steps you told me but It show "Cannot get /" How to fix it

Comment: Where do you get the error? Please ensure the wwwroot folder contains the content from the dist directory. You can do this using the Kudu console.

Comment: Now I used container to deploy my web. It no problem. Thank for your help.

Comment: in my case I have to create git repo in dist\appname\

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a Web.config file in the root folder of your project.

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" />
        </system.web>
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" />
                    </requestFiltering>
            </security>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(?!.*(.chunk.js|.bundle.js|.bundle.map|.bundle.js.gz|.bundle.css|.bundle.css.gz|.png|.jpg|.ico)).*$" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"></conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" appendQueryString="true" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```